# Why does Firefox automatically add "%25/" to my URI?

Tags: url, firefox, urlencode

In a Confluence page there is a link to an external html page like "blah.net/project/latest/index.html". When I work with IE or with Chrome everything is ok. But when clicking this link in Firefox the result is "blah.net/%25/project/latest/index.html".

It seems that this is not a Confluence problem. I entered the url directly into the address field of the browser: the incorrect uri with the "%25/" occurs as well.

Does anybody know what happens and how to avoid it?

Best regards

Comment: `%2F/` or `%25/`?  Does chrome reproduce the issue (the title says yes, the body says no).  I guarantee Firefox doesn't insert a %25 after the domain of every website, so it is either a (1) redirect from confluence, or (2) there is a url encode going on (%25 is `%`, and %2F is `/`), or both.

Comment: I would be inclined to guess that it *is* a Confluence problem, or at least a problem with the specific Confluence site.  That different browsers respond differently in no way contradicts that.  My suspicion is that you're getting a redirection to a URL whose original, unencoded representation is something like `blah.net//project/latest/index.html` or `blah.net///project/latest/index.html`.  That would be subject to encoding, decoding, and possibly normalization spanning both sides of the connection, and it is plausible that the result would vary between user agents.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. @Nathan Merrrill: the issue occurs only in Firefox, the title is wrong. Tried to change it but stackoverflow doesn't allow it ("Title cannot contain "Why Firefox adds "%2F/" to my URI?".) And: %25 is right, i corrected the text.

Comment: Something else to note:  I don't know confluence at all, but typical servers have both a web server layer (nginx or apache) along with the application layer.  The web server is often responsible for redirects and url resolution.  I'd check its configuration to make sure everything is setup correctly.  (It's possible that confluence has abstracted away the web server layer, in which case, I'm not much help)

Comment: Thanks a lot, Merrill, I sent already a ticket to our IT guys.

Comment: Open the [Network Monitor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor) in Firefox, then enter the problematic URL into the Location bar and check if there's any 3xx responses and their response headers...